# excel 2010 vba mssql help : can not get table headers (alias)

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Below is my code and it is working properly, but I have a small problem.

I have two different sheets: in the first sheet, there is a button to get the data. This is working, I can see the data in the second sheet. But the problem is to get the table headers. My code cannot retrieve the headers.

```
    Sub Add_Results_Of_ADO_Recordset() 
     'This was set up using Microsoft ActiveX Data Components version 2.8

    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection 
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 
    Dim stSQL As String 
    Dim wbBook As Workbook 
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet 
    Dim rnStart As Range 


    Const stADO As String = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;SERVER=192.168.0.300;UID=sa;PWD=sa;DATABASE=sa" 

    'where BI is SQL Database & AURDWDEV01 is SQL Server

    Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook 
    Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets(1) 

    With wsSheet 
        Set rnStart = .Range("A1") 
    End With 

    stSQL = "SELECT sModel,sKodu,sAciklama FROM tbstok " 

    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection 

    With cnt 
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient 
        .Open stADO 
        .CommandTimeout = 0 
        Set rst = .Execute(stSQL) 
    End With 

     'Here we add the Recordset to the sheet from A1
    rnStart.CopyFromRecordset rst 

     'Cleaning up.
    rst.Close 
    cnt.Close 
    Set rst = Nothing 
    Set cnt = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show how your excel data looks like?

Comment: @Djerry this is results screenshot [link](http://hanifeoglu.com/excel.png)

Answer (score 2):

hehe. feels weird to modify code that looks almost like my own:)
this creates the headers

```
Dim i As Long
With rst
    For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
        wsSheet.Cells(1, i) = .Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i
End With
```

and this pastes the range starting at A2

```
rnStart.CopyFromRecordset rst
```

rnStart should be set to A2 as the first cell for the recordset to start pasting.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Add_Results_Of_ADO_Recordset()
     'This was set up using Microsoft ActiveX Data Components version 2.8

    Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim stSQL As String
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rnStart As Range


    Const stADO As String = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;SERVER=192.168.0.300;UID=sa;PWD=sa;DATABASE=sa"

    'where BI is SQL Database & AURDWDEV01 is SQL Server

    Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets(1)

    With wsSheet
        Set rnStart = .Range("A2")
    End With

    stSQL = "SELECT sModel,sKodu,sAciklama FROM tbstok "

    Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection

    With cnt
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open stADO
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
    End With

    ' headers
    Dim i As Long
    With rst
     For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
         wsSheet.Cells(1, i) = .Fields(i - 1).Name
     Next i
    End With

    ' add recordset starting at A2
    rnStart.CopyFromRecordset rst

     'Here we add the Recordset to the sheet from A2
    rnStart.CopyFromRecordset rst

     'Cleaning up.
    rst.Close
    cnt.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this final kod very nice, running

Comment: youre welcome you can accept the answer to help identify the solution for future